# Azure Machine Learning - Empty score results

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I've trained a model, the test results on test-set are okay.
Now I have saved the model as 'Trained model' and made a new experiment into a new dataset, for making predictions where I don't have the actual value's.

Normally, the trained model gives me a scored label result per instance. 
But now, the scored label results are empty. Also when I convert the score results to CSV the scored labels column is empty.

Even stranger, when I take a look at the Statistics of the score Visualize tab, I DO see the statistics of the scored values. But no actual scored values...

[image: Screenshot of the empty score results]

Is this a bug? Or am I forgetting something important? Whats going on ;) ?

Comment: Do you mind provided a snapshot of your experiment? I am not following your flow and think you might be missing something...

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for you answer. 
I've attached a screenshot of the experiment. http://i.stack.imgur.com/S2TLb.png. 

As you can see, Ive tried it with 2 different ways;
1. the model below the metadata editors on the left, still uses the traindataset. 
2. the model on the right is the saved model, and uses the same testset as the left side. Both results give an empty scored label set, but do give statistics for the scored column.

Comment: Ive made 2 other models the same way (but other datasets), they do work correctly and give output. This seems like the problem is in the datasets, but the datasets are just normally filled. All needed values are present. Train & test are identical columns and types..

Comment: can you publish your experiment to gallery and share the link - feel free to publish in a unlisted mode and post the link here

Answer (score 1):

If your test dataset is missing the dependent values, your predictive experiment may fail for some models. The solution is to pad your csv file with zero values instead of blank values.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and it was frustrating but I think I finally understand why this is happening.

When I was training my experiment, part of the cleaning process was populating missing values or trimming existing data with R.

The problem is if one of those features is *optional*. For instance if you have a column that is not filled in, the scoring model will fail in the web service.

To see if this problem affects you, go to your Predictive Experiment and visualize the Score Model results. If you see empty Predicted Label & Predicted Score values, you can easily see which data points are missing.